# Forking a piped sub processes

Tags: c, exec, fork

What is the best technique to fork a pipe-lined sub processes?

My current program needs to run another processes that is actually a couple of commands linked by pipes. I do not need to know the output of the commands just if they fail or succeed so I am using fork/exec.

The equivalent on the command line would be

```
 /path/to/A arg1 arg2 | /path/to/B argB1 | /path/to/C
```

Note: Using a script is not practical as it A/B/C may change in the future.

The two techniques I though of are:

1. Recursive fork. Connect the parent (input to its parent) output available for child in next fork.
2. Create all pipes at top level.
   Then use a loop to fork all children that can then connect the pipes appropriately.

Comment: The latter is what shells do, presumably for a good reason.

Comment: @OliCharlesworth: Do you have a reference? Or preferably a link to sample code so I don't re-invent the wheel.

Comment: If you're working on Linux, you can infer this by running `pstree`, which shows the parent-child relationships of all processes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't fork recursively. Making B a subprocess of A is not a good idea. For example, if B calls `setsid` to run in its own session, it would take the unrelated A with it. If B dies, A would get a SIGCHILD, not you. In particular, you would not be able to obtain the return status of B.

Here's a sketch of the code to fork n children on a series of pipes. Warning: I typed the code directly into my browser; there are probably many typos, and I omitted all error checks.

```
char *executables[n];
char *args[n];
int pipes[2*n+2]; /* child i reads from  */
int child_pids[n];
int ret; /*Error checking omitted; abort if ret ever becomes negative*/
ret = pipe(pipes);
for (i = 0; i < n; i++) {
    ret = pipe(pipes + 2 * i + 2);
    ret = fork();
    if (ret == 0) {
        /* Code of child i */
        close(pipes[2*i+1]);
        close(pipes[2*i+2]);
        dup2(pipes[2*i], 0);
        dup2(pipes[2*i+3], 1);
        ret = execv(executables[i], args[i]);
    }
    close(pipes[2*i]);
    close(pipes[2*i+3]);
    child_pids[i] = ret;
}
/* interact with the subprocesses, then call wait or waitpid as needed */
```

Answer (score 0):

If you're on a unix, a simple `system("/path/to/A arg1 arg2 | /path/to/B argB1 | /path/to/C")` will do what you want.  It invokes a shell as `/bin/sh -c $STRING_PASSED_TO_SYSTEM`.  If you want finer control, for example the ability to read the output or write to the input, consider the `popen()` routine in the C library.

Comment: Don't really want to use system() or popen(). Some of the arguments I am using are a bit on the complex side and getting the quoting and escapeing the quotes will get very messey. I want to use the execvp() to make sure the arguments are correctly passed to the sub processes.

Comment: I assure you proper command escaping is a simpler process than creating a working pipe chain.  Or alternatively, wrap the commands that take weird arguments in scripts or variant versions that take their arguments via files, etc...  The process of getting all the pipe()/dup()/fork()/exec() logic correct is hairy and error prone.  And as Oli points out above, the shell has already done it for you.